# ldap3 library: modify attribute with multiple values

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap

Trying to modify an ldap attribute that has multiple values, can't seem to figure out the syntax.

I'm using the [ldap3](https://github.com/cannatag/ldap3) library with python3.

The [documentation](http://ldap3.readthedocs.io/modify.html) gives an example which modifies *two* attributes of an entry - but each attribute only has *one* value.

The dictionary from that example is the bit I'm having trouble with:

```
c.modify('cn=user1,ou=users,o=company',
     {'givenName': [(MODIFY_REPLACE, [<what do I put here>])]})
```

Instead of 'givenname' which would have one value I want to modify the memberuid attribute which obviously would have many names as entries.

So I spit all my memberuids into a list, make the modification, and then am trying to feed my new usernames/memberuid list to the MODIFY command. 
Like so:

```
oldval = 'super.man'
newval = 'clark.kent'

existingmembers = ['super.man', 'the.hulk', 'bat.man']
newmemberlist = [newval if x==oldval else x for x in existingmembers]
# newmemberlist = ", ".join(str(x) for x in newmemberlist)
```

I've tried passing in newmemberlist as a list

```
'memberuid': [(MODIFY_REPLACE, ['clark.kent', 'the.hulk','bat.man'])]
```

which gives me `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

or various combinations (the commented line) of one long string, separated with spaces, commas, semi colons and anything else I can think of

```
'memberuid': [(MODIFY_REPLACE, 'clark.kent, the.hulk, bat.man')]
```

which does the replace but I get *one* memberuid looking like this
  `'clark.kent, the.hulk, bat.man'`

Answer (score 5):

You need to ensure you are passing in the DN of the ldapobject you wish to modify.

```
c.modify(FULL_DN_OF_OBJECT, {'memberuid': [(MODIFY_REPLACE, ['clark.kent', 'the.hulk','bat.man'])]})
```

Then you should be able just to pass in newmemberlist instead of ['clark.kent', 'the.hulk','bat.man']

```
c.modify(FULL_DN_OF_OBJECT, {'memberuid': [(MODIFY_REPLACE, newmemberlist )]})
```

Comment: My list example missed the DN (typo). I've edited my question accordingly. I'm not having problems doing a MODIFY REPLACE when there is one value - however passing a list to get multi-values (like you said) gives the error I showed.

Answer (score 2):

I believe MODIFY_REPLACE command would not accept multiple values, as it would not understand which values would be replaced with new ones. Instead you should try doing MODIFY_DELETE old values first and MODIFY_ADD new values afterwards.

Comment: This is the case for multi value attributes like group membership and the userCertificate field